# How to print back to main function?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#define SIZE 10
int fun1(int x[] , int y[], int limit);
int main(void)
{
    int i,limit ,num1[SIZE],num2[SIZE];

    printf("\n\tPlease enter array size (No more than 10) => ");
    scanf(" %d",&limit); // Array limit
    for(i=0;i<limit;i++)
    {
        printf("\n\tPlease enter num1 (%d) => ",i+1);
        scanf(" %d",&num1[i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<limit;i++)
    {
        printf("\n\tPlease enter num2 (%d) => ",i+1);
        scanf(" %d",&num2[i]);
    }
    fun1(num1,num2,limit);
    getch();
    return 0;
}

int fun1(int x[],int y[] ,int limit)
{
    int i,total[SIZE];
    printf("\n\tInside the function => ");
    for(i=0;i<limit;i++)
    {
        total[i]=x[i]+y[i];
        printf("\n\t %d + %d = %d",x[i],y[i],total[i]);
    }
}
```

Please can you help me to print total back to main. I don 't know how to print total back to main function. I don 't know how to use pointers.

Comment: If you don't know how to use pointers, *learn* how to use them before asking this question

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by "print back to main".  If you want you can print something to a string with sprintf.  Also as @Joseph said if you don't know pointers learn them before you program in C they are essential in C.

Comment: [return arrays from function](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_return_arrays_from_function.htm)

Answer (score 1):

You can also define `total` in `main` and pass it as a parameter to `fun1`, same as you do for `x` and `y`.

This way your function can do the addition and `main` can still do the printing (since `total` would be accessible from `main`)